# Create ToolTip with value from DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tooltip

I have a GridView with 4 visible columns. The DataSource.Select() query bound to this GridView retrieves a 5th column, "Event", of data not seen by the user. I would like to link each row of data in my "Event" column to a ToolTip for each respective row in my GridView. Is this possible?

At the moment I'm using RowCreated event with something like:

```
e.Row.ToolTip = This.GridView.Columns[4].ToString();
```

This adds only the header of the column. How would I get the respective row's value instead?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I wanted by using the RowDataBound event instead. I used a for loop. Here is the code.

```
            for (int i = 0; i <e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            var val = "";
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            { 
                if (drv["Event"] != DBNull.Value)
                { 
                    val = Convert.ToString(drv["Event"]);
                }
            }
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = val;
        }
```